# Append strings to multiple space-separated values in a variable

Tags: awk, sed, variable, string

I have a variable `VAR="XYZ YZA ZAB"` declared and I would like to append some strings next to all the words in that variable.

For example:
I want to append `.file1` to each space-separate substring in `XYZ YZA ZAB`.

The output of variable should be as below without any `for loop` or anything.

```
VAR="XYZ.file1 YZA.file1 ZAB.file1"
```

I am sure `awk` can be used, but I am not aware of how to use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ksh93`:

```
VAR2=${VAR//+([^[:space:]])/\1.file1}
```

Same with `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob
VAR2=${VAR//(#m)[^[:space:]]##/$MATCH.file1}
```

POSIXly:

```
VAR2=$(printf '%s\n' "$VAR" | sed 's/[^[:space:]]\{1,\}/&.file1/g')
```

(beware it strips trailing newline characters if any in `$VAR`).

They all substitute  sequences of one or more (`+(...)`, `##`, `\{1,\}`) characters other than white space ones (`[^[:space:]]`) with the same thing (`\1`, `$MATCH`, `&`) and `.file1` appended.

Or you could split and join if you don't care about preserving the amount of white space between words and words are separated by SPC, TAB and NL (and not other whitespace characters) only:

```
unset IFS # default IFS of SPC+TAB+NL
set -o noglob # disable glob
set -- $VAR # split+glob without glob
for i do
  set -- "$@" "$i.file1" # add suffix
  shift
done
VAR2="$*" # join with space
```

---

With shells with array support, you may want to use an array variable instead of a scalar one. With `rc`/`es`/`zsh`/`ksh93`/`bash`/`mksh`/`yash`:

```
VAR=(XYZ YZA ZAB)
```

Then adding `.file1` to each element (which this time may contain white space themselves) is just a matter of:

```
VAR2=($VAR^.file1) # rc, es
VAR2=($^VAR.file1) # zsh
VAR2=("${VAR[@]/*/\0.file1}") # ksh93
VAR2=("${VAR[@]/%/.file1}") # bash
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution will be to use the shell splitting capability (with a default `IFS`):

```
$ set -f; printf '%s.file1 ' $var; echo
XYZ.file1 YZA.file1 ZAB.file1
```

Understand that that will collapse repeated spaces/tabs to one and that it will remove leading and trailing white-space. The `set -f` will avoid problems with filenames that contain glob characters (`* ? or [`). The printed string in this case will have an additional space.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`, here is a way a little bit shorter than the one from Stéphane:

```
$ VAR="XYZ YZA ZAB"     
$ VAR=( ${^=VAR}.file ) 
$ print -l $VAR
XYZ.file
YZA.file
ZAB.file
```

`=` performs word splitting of the string then `^` "distribute" the suffix to each words.

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion